# Toggle foreach getting value of div class

Tags: jquery, ajax, foreach

I want to get the value of the div class "nameregion", i have to send it by POST in Ajax.
I have a foreach and this is what i tried but it's not working, i received a blank for regionid.

Thanks.

```
foreach($data as $plus) {

if($prev_type != $plus['FRN_TYPE_ENTREE_VALUE']) {
       $prev_type = $plus['FRN_TYPE_ENTREE_VALUE'];
       echo ' <div style="color: #708090; font-size: 24px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 25px; text-align: left;">
       '.$plus['FRN_TYPE_ENTREE_VALUE'].'</div>';
    } 

echo '<a href="#" class="region" value="'.$plus['FRN_TYPE_ENTREE'].'"><img src="images/plus.png" style="float: left; margin-top:-5px; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px;"></a>
<div style="color: #000; font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: left;" class="nameregion" value="oui">'.$plus['FRN_RGN_VALUE'].'</div></a>
<div class="mytoggle"><div class="val"></div></div>';
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".mytoggle").hide();
$('.region').click(function(){
$(this).next().next('.mytoggle').toggle('fast');
var catalogue = "catalogue";
var regionid = $(this).next().val();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'function.php',
            data: {'catalogue': catalogue, 'regionid': regionid },
            success: function (data) {
            $(".val").append(""+data+"").fadeIn(1000);
           }
           });
          $(".val").empty();
    return false; //to avoid the link from working
});
</script>
```

I want to get the value "oui" here :

```
<div style="color: #000; font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: left;" class="nameregion" value="oui">'.$plus['FRN_RGN_VALUE'].'</div></a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change this:

```
var regionid = $(this).next().val();
```

to this:

```
var regionid = $('.nameregion').html();
```

if your div with class `nameregion` is the next element after the element that you have clicked you can use this:

```
var regionid = $(this).next().html();
```

but only if is the next element after your clicked element

---

**UPDATE**

change this

```
<div style="color: #000; font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: left;" class="nameregion" value="oui">'.$plus['FRN_RGN_VALUE'].'</div></a>
```

to this:

```
<div style="color: #000; font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: left;" class="nameregion" data-value="oui">'.$plus['FRN_RGN_VALUE'].'</div></a>
```

and retrieve it in this mode:

```
var regionid = $('.nameregion').data('value');
```

Div element hasn't `value` attribute but you can use data attribute like this: `data-value="oui"`

Comment: If i do that i'm getting '.$plus['FRN_RGN_VALUE'].', i want to get "oui". I will put a different data value after that for each foreach

Comment: div element hasn't value attribute see my update please @user3162341

Comment: Perfect, it's what i wanted, data-value solved my problem thanks

Comment: I have just a little question, if i put for instance '.$plus['FRN_RGN_VALUE_ID'].', in js i get for each of my result "25", so the same, i think i have to use next with data-value ?

Answer (score 1):

`div` elements don't have a `value`. Try using a `data-` attribute:

```
<div data-value="oui"></div>
```

---

```
var regionid = $(this).next().data('value');
```